# MediaWiki slow save of edited pages

Tags: php, mysql, linux, centos, mediawiki

I have MediaWiki 1.16.2 on a the following LAMP platform, which performs quite good for other apps on a 16 GB RAM dual processor machine:
CentOS 5.7 (64-bit)
Apache 2.2.3
MySQL 5.0.77
PHP 5.1.6

It seems to depend somewhat on the used browser, but very frequently saving edited pages is too slow - not rare to wait 10 or 20 seconds for it even more for a very simple change.

Rendering the pages works pretty fast, but it's the saving after editing which is killing the user experience. I have detected some improvement when editing from a client running Opera than on Firefox (on a Fedora Linux platform).

Any hints about where can I tune up the server to make it better ?

Benchmarks of Apache run on the machine are impressive, BTW.

Comment: Sounds like you need to look into the DB, start to metric and performance optimize (write) operations: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization.html

Comment: Additionally you might consider [`memcached`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Memcached)

Comment: Do you have database replication enabled?  Last I checked, that was not enabled by default in the Mediawiki distribution.  But if it were enabled but not configured, that would likely result in the described behavior.

Comment: Try running `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` in the MySQL console while a slow write operation is pending to see if some other query is locking everything up.

Comment: Just as a comment / workaround to my own question. It remains an open issue for me if I think on using Firefox/Fedora. Opera which is my favorite now is much faster and has been a good workaround - no annoying delays.

Comment: Which of the tips at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Performance_tuning have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

Are you logging slow queries in mysql?
Does the mysql error log show anything?

In circumstances like this I would start looking at Cacti.  The mysql-cacti-templates from Percona are invaluable for this.  You will be able to see if you're experiencing an IO issue or a table locking issue.  There could be quite a few causes.

Refs:

http://code.google.com/p/mysql-cacti-templates/

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing out a thought, maybe the saves have more to do with loading external resources? It could be the browser waiting for a response, I have had experiences where slow loads were the result of external JS / content that might be getting slowed down.

Have you investigated that route? Maybe a custom theme or JS editor taking its sweet time.